# Window out of the screen when maximized using WPF shell integration library

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I'm using the [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) to create a custom chrome of my wpf app.
All is good, but when maximizing the app, 6 or 7 pixels are out of the screen.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
        <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <shell:WindowChrome
                    ResizeBorderThickness="6"
                    CaptionHeight="10"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    GlassFrameThickness="1"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#389FD1" Background="#389FD1">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="0,22,0,0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NombreUsuario}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,5,20,5" Opacity=".8" />
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0" Click="WindowMinimize" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="/Resources/Images/minimize.png" />
                            </Button>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0" Click="WindowMaximizeRestore" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" >
                                <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="/Resources/Images/maximize.png" />
                            </Button>
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0" Click="WindowClose" shell:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="/Resources/Images/close.png" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This also occurs when using the `System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome` class (the NuGet package referred to here is no longer needed as this class is now built in to `PresentationFramework.dll`).

Comment: This is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670929/checking-the-value-of-the-windows-windowstate-in-a-trigger

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Windows crops the edges of the window when it's maximized to obscure what would normally be the resize edges.  You can get around this by putting a proxy border between the window and your content and then inflate the thickness when it's maximized.

I modified the example that came with the lib to do this, the same basic change could be made to your sample:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SelectableChromeWindow}">
  <Border BorderBrush="Green">
    <Border.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemParameters2.Current}, Path=WindowResizeBorderThickness}"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Grid [...]/>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I hope that helps.

**For .net 4.5 and above,** the SystemParameters are a little different, e.g.:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: OMG, so beautiful solution. Why didn't I check StackOverflow before start typing my ugly code?

Comment: I have changed to `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">` to make it work, not sure why

Comment: That's better than what I did.  I just happened to have the Window named so I could refer to it that way in my case.

Comment: I still get my window off screen a bit (3 or 4 pixels) when using this solution, but only on the right and bottom. The top and left edges are perfectly aligned.  I'm very confused since all my margins are equal on all sides.

Comment: This does make it better, but my window still goes behind the windows taskbar. How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: @Ristogod: Are you using the WPF Shell Integration Library?

Comment: its good to bind `DataTrigger` to window by using  `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"`

Comment: For .net 4.5 and above user `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>`

Comment: Seems to be off again on Windows 10, about 4 pixels are cropped on each side.

Comment: Its a few pixel to small when the window is maximized. So you can see the Background as a small border.

Comment: @Anthony Brien and other guys, Joe's solution is almost right, see my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
                xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:BorderLessWpf.Views">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Views:ShellView}" >
    <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <shell:WindowChrome
                ResizeBorderThickness="6"
                CaptionHeight="10"
                CornerRadius="0"
                GlassFrameThickness="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: What does caption height do?

Answer (score 7):

## Why is this happening?

[Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/author/oldnewthing) has explained this in his note [Why are the dimensions of a maximized window larger than the monitor?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150304-00/?p=44543):

> The extra eight pixels that hang off the screen are the window
>   borders. When you maximize a window, the window manager arranges
>   things so that the client area of the window fills the width of your
>   work area, and it plus the caption bar fills the height of the work
>   area. After all, you want to see as much of your document as possible;
>   there’s no need to show you the window borders that aren’t doing you
>   any good. (It leaves the caption bar on the screen for obvious
>   reasons.)

## How to handle it?

@Joe Castro has proposed the right approach. You basically have to add a border (or specify a margin) around your window each time it maximizes. And `SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness` is also the right property, but ... **it has a bug**.

For me, it gives `4px` border instead of correct `8px` for 100% display scale (can be changed in `Display Settings`) and approximately `3px` instead of correct `7px` for 175%.

## Why I'm so sure it's a bug and not just the wrong property?

Internally `SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness` uses [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) call to obtain device pixels of the border. It queries for `CXFRAME (32)` and `CYFRAME(33)` indexes, and then converts it into logical pixels.

Now check this [old bug report](http://web.archive.org/web/20130507141206/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753224/regression-getsystemmetrics-delivers-different-values):

> Take the following lines of code:
>
> ```
>     int cx = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
>     int cy = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
>     int cp = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);
> ```
>
> When compiled with Visual Studio 2010, on my Windows7 machine this
>   yields: cx == 9, cy == 9 and cp == 27.
>
> If I compile the very same code with Vision Studio 2012 RC on the same
>   machine, this yields: cx == 5, cy == 5 and cp == 27.

And the answer:

> *Posted by Microsoft on 7/12/2012 at 11:03 AM*
>   Thank you for your bug submission. The issue you reported appears to be a Windows issue, and
>   we have forwarded the bug to them.

But there's some good news from this question: [GetSystemMetrics() returns different results for .NET 4.5 & .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725781/getsystemmetrics-returns-different-results-for-net-4-5-net-4-0)

For .NET 4.5 and later you can just add `SM_CXPADDEDBORDER (92)` value to both `CXFRAME (32)` and `CYFRAME(33)` to get the right values.

## What's the final solution?

Use @Joe Castro approach, but with the fixed property:

```
public static class SystemParametersFix
{
    public static Thickness WindowResizeBorderThickness
    {
        get
        {
            float dpix = GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex.LOGPIXELSX);
            float dpiy = GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex.LOGPIXELSY);

            int dx = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.CXFRAME);
            int dy = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.CYFRAME);

            // this adjustment is needed only since .NET 4.5 
            int d = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
            dx += d;
            dy += d;

            var leftBorder = dx / dpix;
            var topBorder = dy / dpiy;

            return new Thickness(leftBorder, topBorder, leftBorder, topBorder);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

    private static float GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex index)
    {
        IntPtr desktopWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr dc = GetDC(desktopWnd);
        float dpi;
        try
        {
            dpi = GetDeviceCaps(dc, (int)index);
        }
        finally
        {
            ReleaseDC(desktopWnd, dc);
        }
        return dpi / 96f;
    }

    private enum GetDeviceCapsIndex
    {
        LOGPIXELSX = 88,
        LOGPIXELSY = 90
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex nIndex);

    private enum GetSystemMetricsIndex
    {
        CXFRAME = 32,
        CYFRAME = 33,
        SM_CXPADDEDBORDER = 92
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think this is quite a .Net4 vs .Net4.5 bug. The bug that you linked to matches what I expected, where this is related to linking to Comctl32 v6 vs v5. That's why the 2012 RC version had this "bug" as well. In my original version of SystemParameters2 I didn't add in the SM_CXPADDEDBORDER but I didn't test with Comctl 6. I remember this coming up in the VS2010 timeframe but it was an unacceptable breaking change to make 6v default. Looks like in newer versions they went the other way.

Comment: @astef, can you mention, how (where) to use the fixed property? I'm trying to fix the same issue in a `RibbonWindow`

Comment: Posting the xaml so show how the final product should look would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In my project, I have CaptionHeight set to 0 and ResizeMode set to CanResizeWithGrip. This is the code I came up with for the proper thickness.

```
            Thickness maximizeFix = new Thickness(SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Left +
                SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Left,
                SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Top +
                SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Top
                - SystemParameters.CaptionHeight,
                SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Right +
                SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Right,
                SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Bottom +
                SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Bottom);
```

I'm just going to use a border like Joe Castro did and then bind the thickness to a property that I update when the window state changes.

Code seems janky but I haven't found another solution yet.

Comment: If you reference another answer from your answer, consider linking to it, or incorporating part of it (with attribution) to make your answer complete.

Comment: For some reason on Windows 10 this code gives incorrect thikness. It should be 6.5 on my PC but code calculates 5.

Comment: Adding anything else except `WindowResizeBorderThickness` is a mistake. Read my answer to understand why `WindowResizeBorderThickness` is the only right property, and how to make it work

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776985/wpf-unexpected-behavior-of-windowchrome-in-maximized-windows), I thought I would try setting `WindowChrome.NonClientFrameEdges`.

With some experimentation it turns out that you can get the desired effect by setting it to `NonClientFrameEdges.Bottom` when maximised, and setting it back to `NonClientFrameEdges.None` when not maximised.

This makes the margin disappear on all edges except the bottom, but crucially causes the overlap under the taskbar to no longer happen.

It is important that the WindowChrome is set *prior* to the WindowState, so in my code-behind I have the functions (MainGrid2 holds all the window content barring the status bar, and StatusGrid holds the status bar):

```
    private void Maximise()
    {
        StatusGrid.Margin = new Thickness(7, 0, 7, 0);
        MainGrid2.Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 12, 0);            
        chrome.NonClientFrameEdges = NonClientFrameEdges.Bottom;
        WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, chrome); 
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void Restore()
    {
        StatusGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        MainGrid2.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
        chrome.NonClientFrameEdges = NonClientFrameEdges.None;
        WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, chrome);
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue of the window getting out of the screen simply set:

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

See [JAPF's "Set up the main window of your WPF project" post](http://www.japf.fr/2010/12/set-up-main-window-of-your-wpf-project/)
for more info.

Comment: That's just silly, then you cannot resize or full-screen the window.

Comment: @Wobbles if something is fullscreen, why do you need to be able to resize it when it is fullscreen? This solution works nicely on Windows 10 unlike the others, and is a simple fix.

Comment: If that would work I wold be pissed off  because I already lost 2 days on this topic. This may work if you indeed want a full screen, but still you can't just simply say `if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
 window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
else window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;`  on window state change event as it seem you need to have `NoResize` set BEFORE the window is maximized. Also the "full screen" is not the same thing as "maximized" (taskbar visible)... And finally when you set `NoResize` you will lost "Restore" option in thumbnail context menu

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a border around the main content of the window and bound to a property in the ViewModel. When the user presses the maximize button a command is triggered that sets the BorderThickness to 7. When the maximize button is pressed again the BorderThickness is set to 0.

```
    <!-- Content of my window -->
    <Border BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource OffsetBlackBrush}">
            <Grid>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="-" Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" />
                    <Button Content="[ ]" Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}" />
                    <Button Content="X" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource WindowCloseButton}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
    </Border>


<!-- BorderThickness property in VM -->
public int BorderThickness { get; set; } = 0;


    /// <summary>
    /// Maximizes the current window
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand MaximizeCommand
    {
        get => new RelayCommand(param =>
        {
            if (!_view.GetWindowState())
            {
                BorderThickness = 7;
                _view.SetWindowState("Maximize"); // Change window state to maximized using interface passed into ctor
            }
            else
            {
                BorderThickness = 0;
                _view.SetWindowState("Normal");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This will leave 1px line for 100% display scale. And it will still cut your window for large scales (more than 200%). See my answer to understand how to remove this magic number.