# WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, windows-shell, window-chrome

I am styling a Window, but I noticed this strange behaviour of WindowChrome (in .NET FW 4.0, from [external Microsoft.Windows.Shell dll](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4332)).

I set the WindowChrome with AllowTransparency = true and WindowStyle = None.

If I set the WindowChrome's ResizeBorderThickness <= 7 everything works perfectly, but if I do

`ResizeBorderThickness="8"`

or more, when the Window is Maximized I can't drag it from the last top pixel near the top edge of the screen, and for each +1 exceeding 7 I must start dragging 1 pixel more down from the edge.

This is annoying 'cause it disable a common behaviour when closing a window, forcing me to set it to 7 or less.

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Thank you!

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967218/window-out-of-the-screen-when-maximized-using-wpf-shell-integration-library/2975574#2975574

Comment: This is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670929/checking-the-value-of-the-windows-windowstate-in-a-trigger

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The window doesn't have a strange behavior. Instead of it, **the window has two strange behaviors**.

- **(A) First strange behavior**:

> "[...] when the Window is Maximized I can't drag it from the last top pixel near the top edge of the screen [...]"

**This behavior is due to the edge to resize is still active when the window changes to its maximized state. Indeed, this edge is always active.** Setting the *ResizeBorderThickness* property, *WindowChrome* reserve that amount of pixels to control the behavior of resizing the window. Given that in maximized mode the resize events aren't allowed, then you will notice that these pixels don't allow any kind of behavior. This is precisely because *WindowChrome* reserve exclusively those pixels that control the behavior of resizing.

**What is the solution?** You need to notify *WindowChrome* must change to establish the *ResizeBorderThickness* property to 0 when the window is maximized. This can be done simply by setting *WindowChrome* again by a *Trigger* in xaml:

```
<Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
     <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
          <Setter.Value>
               <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="0" [...] />
          </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

*Note: This can also do so in run-time code*

- **(B) Second strange behavior**:

> "[...] If I set the WindowChrome's ResizeBorderThickness <= 7 everything works perfectly [...] and for each +1 exceeding 7 I must start dragging 1 pixel more down from the edge. [...]"

**Take care. Actually this behavior isn't due to the value set in *ResizeBorderThickness* but this is due to set the property *WindowStyle=None***. When this property is set, the window takes on a strange behavior when maximized:

1. The upper left edge of the window is not positioned at the point (0,0) of the current screen, but rather erratically becomes negative (in your case, on the Y axis the value seems to be -7).
2. The size of the window takes the size of the current screen, when the normal behavior should be that the size of the window takes the size of current *work area* (current screen except task bar, etc...) of the current screen.

This strange behavior that takes the window makes that 7 pixels reserved for 'WindowChrome' aren't visible in the current screen (with *ResizeBorderThickness="7"*, obviously), and therefore gives you the feeling that the property *ResizeBorderThickness="7"* works properly, when it isn't. In fact, this justifies the behavior when *ResizeBorderThickness* takes the value 8 or more.

**What is the solution?** It is necessary to *force* the window when maximizing a size and position on the work area of the current screen. *Warning: if you only do it for the primary screen, the maximize event doesn't work properly for multiple screens.*

The code that solves this problem I solved by calling an external API:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);
[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);
```

Defining the classes and structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
public class MONITORINFO
{
      public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));
      public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();
      public RECT rcWork = new RECT();
      public int dwFlags = 0;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
      public int left;
      public int top;
      public int right;
      public int bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
      public int x;
      public int y;
      public POINT(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MINMAXINFO
{
      public POINT ptReserved;
      public POINT ptMaxSize;
      public POINT ptMaxPosition;
      public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
      public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
}
```

And finally defining the functions that add the hook WndProc to the window:

```
public static void CompatibilityMaximizedNoneWindow(Window window)
{
      WindowInteropHelper wiHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
      System.IntPtr handle = wiHelper.Handle;
      HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(
                new HwndSourceHook(CompatibilityMaximizedNoneWindowProc));
}

private static System.IntPtr CompatibilityMaximizedNoneWindowProc(
    System.IntPtr hwnd,
    int msg,
    System.IntPtr wParam,
    System.IntPtr lParam,
    ref bool handled)
{
      switch (msg)
      {
      case 0x0024:    // WM_GETMINMAXINFO
            MINMAXINFO mmi =
                (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

                // Adjust the maximized size and position
                // to fit the work area of the correct monitor
                // int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;
                System.IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, 0x00000002);

                if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero)
                {

                      MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
                      GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
                      RECT rcWorkArea = monitorInfo.rcWork;
                      RECT rcMonitorArea = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
                      mmi.ptMaxPosition.x =
                            Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.left - rcMonitorArea.left);
                      mmi.ptMaxPosition.y =
                            Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.top - rcMonitorArea.top);
                      mmi.ptMaxSize.x =
                            Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.right - rcWorkArea.left);
                      mmi.ptMaxSize.y =
                            Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.bottom - rcWorkArea.top);
                }
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, lParam, true);
                handled = true;
                break;
      }
      return (System.IntPtr)0;
}
```

With *CompatibilityMaximizedNoneWindow* API, you simply call the API in the constructor of the window, something like this:

```
public MyWindow
{
      [...]
      MyNamespace.CompatibilityMaximizedNoneWindow(this);
}
```

And the second strange behavior must be resolved. You will notice that the code to work, you must add reference *PresentationFramework* and the namespace *System.Windows.Interop*.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks dude

Comment: This solution of all I've tried actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a full screen application (`WindowStyle` set to [None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.windowstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-windowstyle-none) and `AllowTransparency` set to `true`) you need to make some tweaks to the otherwise [excellent answer from Noir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24818071/8521):

Instead of using the work area to determine the max boundaries, use the `rcMonitor`:

```cs
mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = 0;
mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = 0;
mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.left - rcMonitorArea.right);                         
mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.bottom - rcMonitorArea.top);
```

To make full screen work, the window need to remove the `WindowChrome` completely when in maximized mode:

```cs
// Run this whenever the window state changes (maximize, restore, ...)
WindowChrome chrome ;
if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
    chrome = null;
else
    chrome = new WindowChrome() { ... }
WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, chrome);
```

By wrapping the logic in a class that can keep state, we can even make our window enter and exit full screen mode at will:

```cs
if (IsFullScreen) 
{
    // Tell Windows that we want to occupy the entire monitor
    mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = 0;
    mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = 0;
    mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.left - rcMonitorArea.right);                         
    mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcMonitorArea.bottom - rcMonitorArea.top);
}
else
{
    // Tell Windows that we want to occupy the entire work area of the
    // current monitor (leaves the task bar visible)
    mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.left - rcMonitorArea.left);
    mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.top - rcMonitorArea.top);
    mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.right - rcWorkArea.left);
    mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.bottom - rcWorkArea.top);
}
```

A complete example with a WPF window using it is available as a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/isaksavo/f080ea9598cedfe65f6eeb9ccecb6760).