# How to display child window in the center of the MainWindow after Maximizing in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, maximize-window

I have child window with Height=300 and Width=400.When i maximize this child window,it gets display on left=0 and top=0 position.I want it to be display in the center of the MainWindow.

**I have tried following ways**

- In Window_StateChanged event, i have tried to change its position as left=100 and    Top=140.The values are assigned,but still it displays on left=0 and Top=0 position.
- I also tried to change its position in Window_SizeChanged event,but it also did not work.
- Then i felt the layout might not refresh,so i refreshed it using this.UpdateLayout(),but not worked.

Comment: "Maximized" and "Centered" don't usually go together... Are you asking how to keep a control centered in your main window?

Comment: I want my child window on same position after maximize.It should increase its size but not position.

Comment: <Window x:Class="MyClass.Window1"
Title="Window1" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Focusable="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="CanResize" MaxHeight="600" MaxWidth="700" LocationChanged="Window_LocationChanged" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged">
</Window>

Comment: There's some interesting stuff going on in here that I haven't completely figured out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967218/window-out-of-the-screen-when-maximized-using-wpf-shell-integration-library (Microsoft.Windows.Shell is found in NuGet)

Answer (score 0):

this may be what you're after

```
    void Window1_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
            this.Left = (App.Current.MainWindow.Width - this.MaxWidth) / 2 + App.Current.MainWindow.Left;
            this.Top = (App.Current.MainWindow.Height - this.MaxHeight) / 2 + App.Current.MainWindow.Top;
            this.Width = this.MaxWidth;
            this.Height = this.MaxHeight;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts bro,but now doing this,the state of the window becomes normal and i wont be able to "Restore Down".